# mod_rewrite + query string changing

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a problem and I'm not sure where it is. My goal is to convert ***mainpage.php?m=5&y=2013*** to ***main/5/2013***. I've looked here for some solutions and tried those flags.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mainpage.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=([0-9]{1,2})&y=([0-9]{4})$
RewriteRule ^mainpage\.php$ http://akamol.info/main/%1/%2? [QSA,L]


Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

it gives me error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /main/5/2013 was not found on this server.

and the link is

> http://akamol.info/main/5/2013?&m=5&y=2013

This was my first option

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mainpage.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=([0-9]{1,2})&y=([0-9]{4})$
RewriteRule ^mainpage\.php$ http://akamol.info/main/%1/%2? [R=302,L]


Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

it's buliding this link

> http://akamol.info/main/5/2013

and it gives me error

> The requested URL /main/5/2013 was not found on this server.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mainpage.php$` *mainpage.php* is not in the request and will never match. Try replacing it with `/main/`. But not sure I understand what you need. Does this path `/main/5/2013` exists? If not, why redirecting to it? If the idea is to have a "pretty" URL but still get the data from the original request with the query, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780531/htaccess-to-convert-query-string-never-works/16783367#16783367)

Comment: I'm not sure it's really my case there. I want to get a pretty URL but I still have to pass with a $_GET 2 variables. And they are not directory pass or some specific folders. It's 2 integers. Is this possible at all? I mean if I want to rewrite index.php?a=1&b=2 to index.php/1/2 where /1/2 are 2 vars can I still get them as $_GET['a'] and $_GET['b'] from this link? I thought that rewriting is working only at the client side but the server will see all the links as they suppose to be (?a=1&b=2).

Comment: I've just started to learn mod_rewrite and probably I don't understand some basic rools. If somebody have a good totorial exept the official site (already was there) I will be glad to get the link as well.

Comment: That's what the answer I suggested does, just modify the variables accordingly.