# .htaccess to convert query string never works

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

**The goal:**
To have a query string converted into a nice looking URL, which I have never gotten to work.

**The details:**
Change this URL:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/static-directory/index.php?state=florida&city=tallahassee`

to this one:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/static-directory/florida/tallahassee`

**What I have tried:**
Well, just about everything.  My latest search came up with this [tutorial](http://www.gerillafilm.se/web/ultimate-htaccess-rewrite-tutorial-with-301-redirects/)...

I have my `.htaccess` file in my root directory (httpdocs).

Any help or point me at the right answered question on Stack Overflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **QUESTION:**
>   "Change this URL: `.../static-directory/index.php?state=florida&city=tallahassee` 
>   
> to this one: `.../static-directory/florida/tallahassee`"

According to the question, all is needed is to convert the 1st URL (The Request) with the query to the 2nd one without a query.

Here is a way to achieve that in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /static-directory/index.php\?state=([^&]+)&city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule  ^static-directory/index.php  /static-directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NC]
```

However, just in in case the OP forgot to mention the whole idea is to remove the query in order to have a "pretty" URL but still get the data from the original URL, add next 2 lines to the rule-set:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule  ^static-directory/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /static-directory/index.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L]
```